# HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed | Jersey | REST WS Call | PUT & DELETE

Tags: rest, web-services, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

-Code for Exposing Resource:

```
@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {
 @PUT
@Path("/{messageId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public MessageEntity updateMessage(MessageEntity messageEntity, @PathParam("messageId") long messageId) {
    messageEntity.setMessageId(messageId);
    return new MessageService().updateMessage(messageEntity);
}
```

}

URI to test: http://localhost:8080/rest-webservice-app/webapi/messages/1

I am testing using Postman (So not a problem with Method being called), and every time I do get the same error :

HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

I snooped around stack overflow and other blogs/forums for the answer, but nothing seems to work.

Read about the firewalls of the PUT/DELETE request too but doesn't seem to be a firewall issue in case we are testing in local dev env.

The POST and GET are working fine.

The issue is with DELETE and POST.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Server hosted on : tomcat 9.0.8

Comment: Error:

h1>HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Method Not Allowed</p><p><b>Description</b> The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.</p>

Comment: @Priyank dey : have you added the class to the configuration?

Comment: @Saif Ali : Yes I did.

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.priyak.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

com.priyak.resources contais all the endpoints.

Comment: This is strange as from the same class , I can access all my POST and GET requests but in case of PUT and DELETE I do get the same error. Some digging shows some firewall for PUT and DELETE requests. But localhost should not be affected by that right?

Comment: Any Updates from anyone ?

Comment: can you make a gist for the class and the configuration will check that?